# Getting Error 000212: Cannot create XY event source Failed to execute (Make XY Event Layer). using ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, error-000212

I have a model created in ModelBuilder using ArcGIS Desktop that works on PC1 set up with relative paths and workspaces. When I try run it on PC2 I get an error message statin

> Error 000212: Cannot create XY event source Failed to execute (Make XY
>   Event Layer).

with the exact same files. I tried again an run it on P1 again with the same files and it works.

Can you advise?

Comment: What does your simplest test model which can reproduce this look like?

Comment: Have you reviewed the earlier Q&As with this error message?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000212?tab=Votes